# Printing out the value from a Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, int, printf

In the following example, how would I print out the value in u? I keep on printing out the address.

```
int example (float f) 
{ 
    unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f;
    printf("The value in u is: %u\n", u);
}
```

EDIT

I have something like this:

```
int example (float f) 
{ 
    unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f;

    if((u&u) && u != MASK) {

     printf("The value in u is: %u\n", u);

     printf("The address in u is: %u" , u);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    example(3);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The problem that I have is when I try to check and print out the value of 'u'.
I can't seem to get it to print out.

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: If I were to put a value in u for example:

u = u&mask;

if I wanted to see the actual value in u how would I print it out instead of getting the address?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f;` ? Converting a `float` to an `unsigned int`?

Comment: Your code contains a ton of syntax errors...

Comment: The code is seeking to see what the data in a `float` looks like when interpreted as an integer — what are the bits that make up the float.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now I see, right.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes that is what I was attempting to do, just to check that the mask I use gives me the desired effect. That is why I attempt to print out the value in u

Comment: @ouah yea, with the unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f; I am trying to make a pointer of type unsigned int

Comment: @Mus but your code is `unsigned int u = *(unsigned int)&f;` not `unsigned int u = (unsigned int)&f;`

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)); it is so much simpler when we can see what you see.  My answer, for example, is complete and compilable and I can show the output; why can't you create your example as similarly small and compilable and show the output you get and explain the output you're expecting?  `u&u` will be 'true' unless `u==0`; you don't show us `MASK`, but you seem to be treating it as a value (mask normally applies to an operand of `&`, `|` or perhaps `^`).

Comment: Don't forget that MarkDown confuses code in comments unless the code is enclosed in back-quotes.  Without back-quotes: unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f; but with back-quotes: `unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f;` — and the absence of a space before the second asterisk is critical.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of your code that compiles and runs OK under GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static void example(float f) 
{ 
    unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f;
    printf("%13.6e: %10u = 0x%08X (address 0x%08" PRIXPTR ")\n",
           f, u, u, (uintptr_t)&f);
}

int main(void)
{
    example(+3.14159F);
    example(+0.0);
    example(-0.0);
    example(+3.456789e24);
    example( 3.456789e-24);
    example(-3.456789e24);
    example(-3.456789e-24);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
 3.141590e+00: 1078530000 = 0x40490FD0 (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
 0.000000e+00:          0 = 0x00000000 (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
-0.000000e+00: 2147483648 = 0x80000000 (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
 3.456789e+24: 1748435002 = 0x6837003A (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
 3.456789e-24:  411417185 = 0x1885BA61 (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
-3.456789e+24: 3895918650 = 0xE837003A (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
-3.456789e-24: 2558900833 = 0x9885BA61 (address 0x7FFF5FD3754C)
```

As you can see, I use a 64-bit machine.  You can see in the hex that the sign bit is in the most significant byte; less obvious is that the exponent is in the next 8 bits, and the mantissa in the remaining 23 bits.

Your code is very close to what I'm demonstrating — once the typos were fixed.  Your code using `MASK` is mysterious since you don't show what `MASK` is.  However, it should print the information for almost any float value except positive zero (because then `u&u` evaluates to false) or the one specific float value that has a bit pattern that matches `MASK`.

For my code, the compiler warns:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
      -Wold-style-definition x.c -o x
x.c: In function ‘example’:
x.c:6:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
$
```

Here is another extension, and more sample output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static void example(float f) 
{ 
    unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&f;
    unsigned int s = u >> 31;
    unsigned int e = (u >> 23) & 0xFF;
    unsigned int m = (u >> 16) & 0x7F;
    printf("%13.6e: %10u = 0x%08X (s=%u, e=x%02X, m=0x%02X) (0x%08" PRIXPTR ")\n",
           f, u, u, s, e, m, (uintptr_t)&f);
}

int main(void)
{
    example(+3.14159F);
    example(+0.0);
    example(-0.0);
    example(+1.0);
    example(-1.0);
    example(+2.0);
    example(-2.0);
    example(+3.0);
    example(-3.0);
    example(+4.0);
    example(-4.0);
    example(+5.0);
    example(-5.0);
    example(+3.456789e24);
    example( 3.456789e-24);
    example(-3.456789e24);
    example(-3.456789e-24);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
 3.141590e+00: 1078530000 = 0x40490FD0 (s=0, e=x80, m=0x49) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 0.000000e+00:          0 = 0x00000000 (s=0, e=x00, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-0.000000e+00: 2147483648 = 0x80000000 (s=1, e=x00, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 1.000000e+00: 1065353216 = 0x3F800000 (s=0, e=x7F, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-1.000000e+00: 3212836864 = 0xBF800000 (s=1, e=x7F, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 2.000000e+00: 1073741824 = 0x40000000 (s=0, e=x80, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-2.000000e+00: 3221225472 = 0xC0000000 (s=1, e=x80, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 3.000000e+00: 1077936128 = 0x40400000 (s=0, e=x80, m=0x40) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-3.000000e+00: 3225419776 = 0xC0400000 (s=1, e=x80, m=0x40) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 4.000000e+00: 1082130432 = 0x40800000 (s=0, e=x81, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-4.000000e+00: 3229614080 = 0xC0800000 (s=1, e=x81, m=0x00) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 5.000000e+00: 1084227584 = 0x40A00000 (s=0, e=x81, m=0x20) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-5.000000e+00: 3231711232 = 0xC0A00000 (s=1, e=x81, m=0x20) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 3.456789e+24: 1748435002 = 0x6837003A (s=0, e=xD0, m=0x37) (0x7FFF6112754C)
 3.456789e-24:  411417185 = 0x1885BA61 (s=0, e=x31, m=0x05) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-3.456789e+24: 3895918650 = 0xE837003A (s=1, e=xD0, m=0x37) (0x7FFF6112754C)
-3.456789e-24: 2558900833 = 0x9885BA61 (s=1, e=x31, m=0x05) (0x7FFF6112754C)
```

This is beginning to analyze the [IEEE 754 single-pricision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) in some detail.  The referenced Wikipedia page gives more information on why the values I used for creating `s`, `e`, `m` are of relevance (noting that I'm working on an Intel machine and hence this is little-endian data).

Except with the 'gradual underflow' values, zeros, infinities and NaNs, the first bit of the 'real' mantissa is always a 1, so the format does not actually store that.  You can see this from the values for 1, 2, 4 — contrast with 3 and 5 (each of which has only one bit set in the mantissa, even though the binary representation of 3 and 5 contains two set bits).